# filter 2 columns show output results for column 3 numpy python

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have 3 columns that I have stacked. What I want to do now is filter column1 >2 and column2 >=25 when these both meet the criteria show results for column3.

This is what I have so far for

```
xo = numpy.column_stack((weather_bucket[:-1],weather_bucket[:-1],allofthem_array[1:]))

xx = xo[xo[:,0]>2,:]
```

How can I tell python/ numpy to filter column1 and column2 and show results from column3?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `filter`?  Give a sample `xo` array, and desired `xx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should do it:

```
idx = np.where(np.logical_and(xo[:,0] > 2, xo[:,1] >= 25))[0]
xx = xo[idx, 2]
```

I took a habit to use np.logical_and instead of &&, personal preference. Note there is no reason for stacking the arrays beforehand for doing this, or precise your intentions.